# Price of fake SIN

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, errata

All I can find about the Availability and pricing of fake SINs in the Core rulebook is:

> For availability and prices of purchasing Fake SINs, see p. 367

No such information on page 367. Has there been an errata?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Page 443 of the Core Rulebook in the Identification section states:

> ```
> Type                   |  Avail         |  Cost
> Fake Sin (Rating  1-6) |  (Rating x 3)F |  Rating x 2,500¥
> ```